# Angular2 Support in Bernii gauge

Tags: typescript, jsgauge

is this library [bernii/gauge.js](http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/) supported in angular2 in accordance with typescript?
.Please help.

Comment: why shouldn't it be?

Comment: Also please have a look at the how to ask guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask